# Fitness too low when baking

Tags: baking, baker, error, testnet

I recently started running a node on the edo2net test network. The endorser has been working fine.

I had rights to bake a couple of blocks today, but both times the baker failed with a "Fitness too low" error:

```
tezos-baker-008-PtEdo2Zk[314539]: Mar 22 22:21:45.171 - 008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.forge: Error while injecting block  
<block data here>
tezos-baker-008-PtEdo2Zk[314539]: Mar 22 22:21:45.199 - 008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.forge:     Error:  
tezos-baker-008-PtEdo2Zk[314539]: Mar 22 22:21:45.199 - 008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.forge:       Fitness too low
```

Any ideas on how would I find out the cause of this error?